# good ruby yaml library

Tags: ruby, yaml

I am trying to read a yaml file similar to this

```
SLTs:
      - requests: 600
        concurrency: 50
        targets:
          99%: < 100
          Requests per second: > 500
```

Notice that the key "Requests per second" has spaces in it. I have read the yaml specs in yaml.org and it seems that this is OK.

Ruby 1.9.2 came with 2 yaml libraries psych and syck. 
Psych is not able to read this file

```
couldn't parse YAML at line 132 column 37 (Psych::SyntaxError)
```

Syck is able to parse it but it does not work correctly with Delayed Job (another integral part of my system).

I have tried 1.9.3 with similar results.

The engine for YAML can be changed with YAML::ENGINE.yamler = ...  but I would rather not play with changing the engine for each case and use a library that works correctly in both cases.

I have googled for it but could not find anything so my question is: There exists a better library than those in the Ruby standard library to process YAML ? I only need to read files.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It’s not the spaces in the key that’s causing the problem, it’s the value: `> 500`. [`>` indicates a scalar in folded style](http://yaml.org/spec/1.1/#>%20folded%20style/) – the error is saying that after the `>` there should only be a comment or a newline.

You’ll need to escape the values for your hash:

```
 99%: '< 100'
 Requests per second: '> 500'
```

Comment: I don't know whether you are right, but yo say it so cooly, that I couln't help myself but upvote you :)

Comment: Awesome. This is exactly what was happening. Would never figure it out.